# principal component analysis or factor analysis to be used with qualitative data

Tags: regression, variance, pca, covariance, factor-analysis

I want to make a model in which the dependent variable is nutritional levels of children, for this, I calculated $z$ scores like `weight` for `age` and `height` for `age`. For the independent variables, I need to calculate a female empowerment index which includes questions like:

1. Do you have any take on deciding what to be cooked today?     yes or no
2. Are you beaten by your husband?        yes or no

and so on...

I want to ask is it possible to use PCA in this and combine $10$ or more questions in a single index and then regress on $z$ scores already calculated?

Comment: Yes. (The outcome variable is irrelevant.)

Comment: People will be  best able to help if you carefully proofread your question.  Where are the qualitative data of the title?  Are you sure you haven't reversed independent and dependent?  "Regress ... on..." means that a dependent variable is modeled based on 1 or more independent variables; are you sure you are using this phrase correctly?